# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, annotations

I am newbie in spring MVC. I am writing CRUD Spring MVC application to understand the flow of spring MVC.
I am getting an error `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed`.

I searched for solution of this error but could not find the exact solution for this. There are multiple question are there on `stackoverflow`. but I am really not able to understand what is the cause of this error and how do I fix it.

**Stack Trace**

```html
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.varun.contact.dao.ContactDao com.varun.contact.controller.HomeController.contactDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.varun.contact.dao.ContactDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:362)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.varun.contact.dao.ContactDao com.varun.contact.controller.HomeController.contactDao; nested exc
14:25:39,988 INFO  [STDOUT] eption is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.varun.contact.dao.ContactDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
... 75 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.varun.contact.dao.ContactDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
... 77 more
```

**Contact.java**

```html
public class Contact {
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private String email;
 private String address;
 private String telephone;

// Default Constructor
// Parameterized Constructor

//Getters and setters
   }
```

**ContactDao**

```html
public interface ContactDao {
 
 public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact);
 public void delete(int contactId);
 public Contact get(int contactId);
 public List<Contact> list();
}
```

**ContactDaoImpl**

```html
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDao {
 
 private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
 
 
  public ContactDAOImpl(javax.activation.DataSource dataSource) {
       jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate((DataSource) dataSource);
   
     }
  //Insert or update a new contact: 
 @Override
 public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact) {
  if(contact.getId()>0){
   //Update
   String sql="UPDATE CONTACT SET name=?,email=?,address=?,"
   +"telephone=? where contact_id=?";
   System.out.println("I am inside ContactDAOImpl : save or saveOrUpdate------------------------------------------------");
   jdbcTemplate.update(sql,contact.getName(),contact.getEmail(),contact.getAddress(),
     contact.getTelephone(),contact.getId());
  }
  else{
   // Insert
   String sql="INSERT INTO CONTACT(name,email,address,telephone)"
     +"VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
   jdbcTemplate.update(sql,contact.getName(),contact.getEmail(),contact.getAddress(),
     contact.getTelephone());
  }
  
 }

 
 //Delete a contact:
 @Override
 public void delete(int contactId) {
 String sql="DELETE FROM CONTACT where contact_id=?";
 System.out.println("I am inside ContactDAOImpl : save or delete -----------------------------------------------------------");
 jdbcTemplate.update(sql,contactId);
  
 }

 //Get a particular contact:
 @Override
 public Contact get(int contactId) {
 
  String sql="SELECT * FROM CONTACT WHERE contact_id="+contactId;
   return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<Contact>() {
    
          @Override
          public Contact extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                  DataAccessException {
              if (rs.next()) {
                  Contact contact = new Contact();
                  contact.setId(rs.getInt("contact_id"));
                  contact.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                  contact.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                  contact.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                  contact.setTelephone(rs.getString("telephone"));
                  return contact;
              }
   
              return null;
          }
   
      });
 }
 
 //List all contact:
 @Override
 public List<Contact> list() {
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM contact";
   System.out.println("I am inside List contact-------------------------- ");
     List<Contact> listContact = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Contact>() {
    
  
         @Override
         public Contact mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
             Contact aContact = new Contact();
  
             aContact.setId(rs.getInt("contact_id"));
             aContact.setName(rs.getString("name"));
             aContact.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
             aContact.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
             aContact.setTelephone(rs.getString("telephone"));
             return aContact;
         }
        });
     return listContact;
 }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```html
@Controller
public class HomeController {
  
 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
 @Autowired
 private ContactDao contactDao;

 //Handler method for listing all contacts (also served as home page):
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
     List<Contact> listContact = contactDao.list();
     model.addObject("listContact", listContact);
     model.setViewName("home");
     return model;
}
    //Handler method for displaying new contact form:
 @RequestMapping(value = "/newContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView newContact(ModelAndView model) {
     Contact newContact = new Contact();
     model.addObject("contact", newContact);
     model.setViewName("ContactForm");
     return model;
 }
 
 //Handler method for inserting/updating a contact:
 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView saveContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) 
 {
 contactDao.saveOrUpdate(contact);
 return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
 }
  
 //Handler method for retrieving details of a particular contact for editing:
 @RequestMapping(value = "/editContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView editContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
     int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
     Contact contact = contactDao.get(contactId);
     ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ContactForm");
     model.addObject("contact", contact);
     return model;
 }
}
```

**MVCConfiguration**

```html
package com.varun.contact.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.varun.contact")
@EnableWebMvc
@Repository
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 
 @Bean
 public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
     return resolver;
 }
 
 @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
 
  @Bean
     public DataSource getDataSource() {
         DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
         dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl");
         dataSource.setUsername("system");
         dataSource.setPassword("admin");
         return (DataSource) dataSource;
     }

   @Bean
     public ContactDao getContactDao() {
         return new ContactDAOImpl(getDataSource());
     }
}
```

**ContactForm.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>New/Edit Contact</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>New/Edit Contact</h1>
        <form:form action="saveContact" method="post" modelAttribute="contact">
        <table>
           <tr>
                <td>Id:</td>
                <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><form:input path="address" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Telephone:</td>
                <td><form:input path="telephone" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Home.jsp**

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Contact Manager Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>
 Welcome.............................. 
</h1>
<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P> 


<div align="center">
<h1>Contact List</h1>
 <h3><a href="/newContact">New Contact</a></h3>
            <table border="1">
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Telephone</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                 
                <c:forEach var="contact" items="${listContact}" varStatus="status">
                <tr>
                    <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                    <td>${contact.name}</td>
                    <td>${contact.email}</td>
                    <td>${contact.address}</td>
                    <td>${contact.telephone}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/editContact?id=${contact.id}">Edit</a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="/deleteContact?id=${contact.id}">Delete</a>
                   </td>
                             
              </tr>
         </c:forEach>             
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Web.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>ContactForm.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 
 
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 
 <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <!-- Processes application requests -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
 <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

</web-app>
```

Please help me I am really not able to understand what is wrong with this

Comment: if not add then <context:component-scan base-package="com" /> in servlet-context.xml

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem of injecting ContactDAO in the controller.

Mark your ContactDAOImpl with @Repository annotation and check the package where the ContactDAOImpl is located is included in the `scan` of your configuration

Comment: Did the same but still I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Spring the location from which to pick up the bean. To do this:

1. Annotate `ContactDAOImpl` with `@Repository`
2. In your xml config add a line:

   ```
   <context:component-scan base-package="dao packagename" />
   ```

By doing this you are referring to the location, where the bean needs to be picked up from.